# What would be the correct algorithm to solve our problem in Neo4j database?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, graph, neo4j

Our problem:

Given a one start point (node) or more (nodes) we want to create a directed tree (hierarchical) graph in `Neo4j`. We have the restriction that all directions are always one-way. Further we know what nodes are connected, but we don't know the end nodes.

We are looking for an algorithm which can find inside graph in a way that given the start point all end points can be reached.

[image: algorithm]

Answer (score 0):

I think [Minimum Weight Spanning Tree](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/alpha-algorithms/minimum-weight-spanning-tree/) would meet your requirement.

Create your in-memory graph with undirected relationships, and give all relationships a weight of 1. Pass the node id for node 100 as the startNodeId parameter.